# How to use contains and replace in power query together?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I am trying to add a step in power query to replace any value "?" with UNKNOWN, but I need to add some sort of conditional or contains statement, and have not been able to figure out how to make it work.

Here is a sample of what the city values look like

[image]

and if I use something like this:

```
 = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercased Text","?","UNKNOWN",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"City"})
```

it will give results like

[image]

but I just want it to displace "UNKNOWN" once. I have been trying to combine the below with an if statement or contains, but not been able to make it work correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If statement like this should work:

```
#"Replace" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Uppercased Text", each [City], each if Text.Contains([City], "?") then "UNKNOWN" else [City], Replacer.ReplaceValue, {"City"})
```